# Як перекласти: "...but when he is about to plunge into the deeps..."?

Tags: from-english, вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами

"...одначе, перед тим як зануритися у глибини океану..."

Наскільки тут гарно виглядає "глибини океану"? Може, краще "вглиб океану"?

Я не бачу проблеми з самим словом "глибини", воно, здається, якнайкраще по змісту підходить, але чи гарно воно звучить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Безліч письменників вживає саме «в/у глибини» (що, судячи з усього, є первісною формою для «вглиб/углиб»):

- Його сухе жовте обличчя розгладилося, прозорі очі сяяли, вдивляючись задумливо в глибини неба. <sub>//Олесь Бердник «Подвиг Вайвасвати» (1965).</sub>
- А може, є захований потяг у людині — перш ніж спуститися в глибини моря, зійти на вершини гір. <sub>//Павло Загребельний «Переходимо до любові» (1971).</sub>

Мені здається, що «в глибини океану» може натякати на більшу глибину за «вглиб океану» (як не дивно це звучить). Бо в другому випадку об'єктом, до якого звертається моя увага, є океан — а «вглиб» може бути лише позначенням напрямку (навіть не обов'язково великої міри, можна «зануритися вглиб на 1 м чи на 5 см»); а в першому ж моя уява звертається саме до «глибин» (стиль і множина підкреслюють, що це значення 2 — «те, що на *великій* відстані від поверхні», а не значення 1 — «*якась* відстань від поверхні; числова міра відстані від поверхні» (номери 1 і 2 [звідси](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=186120&page=639)); тобто про «занурення на 5 см» тут вже аж ніяк не йдеться).

Але що стилістично краще у Вашому випадку — вирішувати Вам.

Comment: дякую, мені тепер зрозуміло, чому саме глибини тут підходять якнайкраще.